# DRF Каскадное создание записей

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Написаны три модели: модель `Machine`, модель `Operation` и модель `OperationCard`:

Класс `Machine` является описанием объекта некоторой "машины", который требуется собрать:

```
class Machine(models.Model):...
```

Класс `OperationCard` является детальным описанием операции, которую необходимо сделать во время сборки `Machine`, без привязки к конкретному `Machine`. Просто описание операции:

```
class OperationCard(models.Model):...
```

Класс `Operation` показывает список операций, относящихся к конкретной `Machine` и описываемых конкретной `OperationCard`:

```
class Operation(models.Model):
    operation_card = models.ForeignKey("backend_api.OperationCard")  
    machine_id = models.ForeignKey(
       "backend_api.Machine",
       verbose_name = ("Assigned Machine id")
    ),
    ...
```

Необходимо при создании новой записи `Machine` методом `POST` автоматически создавать список операций `Operation`, каждая их которых описывается `OperationCard`. Количество создаваемых операций на текущем этапе разработки жёстко задано.

Каким образом можно интегрировать функцию во `View`, чтобы, при создании новой записи `Machine` происходило автоматическое создание записей `Operation` с внешним ключом свежесозданной `Machine`?

что-то вроде такого:

```
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView

from backend_api.models import Machine
from .serializers import MachineModelSerializer


class MachineCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Machine.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MachineModelSerializer
    """ Здесь добавить код создания операций к создающейся Machine """
```